# Python, how do i get the entry to be attached to the label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*

class contactMain:

    def __init__(self, master):
        #First Label Heading
        self.heading = Label(master, text='CONTACT REGISTRY', bg='blue', fg='white', width=30)
        self.heading.grid(row=0,column=0)
        #Space between the heading and the first
        self.spaceHF = Label(master,bg='blue',fg='white', width=30)
        self.spaceHF.grid(row=1, column=0)
        #firstName label and entry
        self.fNameLabel = Label(master,text='First Name' ,bg='white', fg='blue',width=15)
        self.fNameLabel.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.fNameEntry = Entry(master)
        self.fNameEntry.grid(row=2,column=1)

root = Tk()
app = contactMain(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try using a getter and setter?

Comment: What do you mean by "attached"? Do you mean visually connected? Do you mean when you change the entry, the label changes? Something else?

Comment: visually connected

Answer (score 0):

Your question was not very clear but I think you want the entry next to the label. This can be done by having the headings span several columns: `columnspan=2`. I also stretch the headings to fill the width of the cells: `sticky=EW`. Have a look at this example; is that what you want?

```
from tkinter import*

class contactMain:
    def __init__(self, master):
        #First Label Heading
        self.heading = Label(master, text='CONTACT REGISTRY', bg='blue',fg='white', width=30)
        self.heading.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=EW)
        #Space between the heading and the first
        self.spaceHF = Label(master,bg='blue',fg='white', width=30)
        self.spaceHF.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=EW)
        #firstName label and entry
        self.fNameLabel = Label(master,text='First Name' ,bg='white', fg='blue',width=15)
        self.fNameLabel.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

        self.fNameEntry = Entry(master)
        self.fNameEntry.grid(row=2,column=1)

root = Tk()
app = contactMain(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if you think it was of use to you.